# C# SignalR Winform Streaming

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr, signalr-hub, visual-studio-2019

I have a messenger in c# windows application to send Text messages between clients.

> (.Net framework 4.7.2 - Vs 2019)

**It works great.**
I must add **voice and video streaming** to this application!
I want to help me how can I do that ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If my question is Duplicate please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

there are examples of streaming video using SignalR(HTML5 is used there, but this stream can also be played in WinForms) [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/video-streaming-with-asp-net-signalr-and-html5)

General information on streams in SignalR is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I hope my answer was helpful :)